# pygame, video not initialized and no video found - using ubuntu terminal from within windows 10

Tags: python, pygame

I know these kinds of questions have been asked many times.  But I have searched very hard, and tried various suggestions, none of which worked.  This type of stuff really isn't in my wheelhouse and I have no idea what I am doing.

What is crazy is I actually had this working yesterday, and today I swear I didn't change anything and suddenly it wasn't working.

I am running "xming server", which I believe should allow X11 to work within windows (it did yesterday!).

Here is my code (literally copy and pasted from a tutorial):

```
import pygame
from pygame.locals import *

def main():

    pygame.init() 


    #pygame.display.list_modes()


    logo = pygame.image.load("myguy.bmp")
    pygame.display.set_icon(logo)
    pygame.display.set_caption("minimal program")   

    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((1024,768))

    running = True

    while running:

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False 


if __name__=="__main__":

    main()
```

**output**:

> pygame 1.9.4
>
> Hello from the pygame community.
>
> https://www.pygame.org/contribute.html
>
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:768:(parse_card) cannot find card '0'
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function
>   snd_func_card_driver
>
> returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:392:(snd_func_concat) error evaluating strings
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_concat
>   returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib confmisc.c:1251:(snd_func_refer) error evaluating name
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4292:(_snd_config_evaluate) function snd_func_refer
>   returned error: No such file or directory
>
> ALSA lib conf.c:4771:(snd_config_expand) Evaluate error: No such file
>   or directory
>
> ALSA lib pcm.c:2266:(snd_pcm_open_noupdate) Unknown PCM default
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "game.py", line 42, in
>   
>       main()   File "game.py", line 17, in main
>       pygame.display.set_icon(logo) pygame.error: No available video device

If I try to list display modes, the output error at the end changes to:
"pygame.error: video system not initialized"

Thank you for any help or suggestions

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem.

export DISPLAY=:0

I had to type that in the terminal.